# Passing data to view not working - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
        Redirect::to('home');
    }
    $user = Auth::user();
    return View::make('HumanResourcesProcess')->with(array('firstName', $user->firstName));
```

and it gives me the error:

```
Undefined variable: firstName
```

But I am defining it in the array part?
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Don't cast to an array to pass to the view

Comment: The [array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) is a function (not a cast) and will create an array. With the comma `,` as delimiter it generates an array with two elements, with the `=>` it generates an array with one key-value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return View::make('HumanResourcesProcess')->with('firstName', $user->firstName);
```

or this one:

```
return View::make('HumanResourcesProcess')->with(array('firstName' => $user->firstName) );
```

I hope it works fine.

Comment: This works just fine, but on tutorials I have seen them casting to arrays? what can that be used for?

Comment: That's because you didn't set the value for `firstName` key of the array. I edited the answer to add it.

Comment: with the second one, would I be able to pass more variables through as it is an array?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you can use is 'compact', especially useful if you have lot's of variable to pass without having to assign them when passing to view:

```
return View::make('view.name',compact('variable1','variable2','variable3'));
```